# Unit testing in JavaScript with Jest

Tags: javascript, html, testing, jestjs

I am working on a JavaScript seconds and milliseconds stop watch with `setInterval` and am having an `update()` function that updates milliseconds after every millisecond. The milliseconds updates seconds with one second after every 999 milliseconds. I am having problem with writing a unit test in Jest for `update()` function. Update function returns the seconds/milliseconds html elements innerTexts and I am rendering the format based on conditional rendering with if/else statements. I am not good at writing unit tests for functions with if/else conditional rendering. Please help me to write unit test for this update function with Jest testing Library without judging, for I am learning to perfect. Thank you in advance.

Here is the code I am working on:

```
let sec = 0;
let ms = 0;
const secEl = document.getElementById("seconds");
const msEl = document.getElementById("milli_seconds");
let play = false;
const maxMilliSec = 999;
const myMin = 10;
const myMax = 100;
const stopwatch = setInterval(function () {
  if (!play) {
    return;
  }

  if (ms === maxMilliSec) {
    ms = 0;
    sec += 1;
  } else {
    ms += 1;
  }
  update(myMin, myMax);
}, 1);

const update = function (myMin, myMax) {
  const secLeadingZero = 0;
  const msLeadingZero = 0;
  if (ms < myMin) {
    msEl.innerText = `${msLeadingZero}${msLeadingZero}${ms}`;
  } else if (ms > myMin && ms < myMax) {
    msEl.innerText = `${msLeadingZero}${ms}`;
  } else if (ms > myMax) {
    msEl.innerText = ms;
  } else if (sec < myMin) {
    secEl.innerText = `${secLeadingZero}${sec}`;
  } else if (sec > myMin) {
    secEl.innerText = sec;
  } else {
    return "Invalid time format";
  }
};
```

I tried to import the `update()` function in my index.test.js file and tried to test it by expecting `update()` to return value based on the arguments passed but it was throwing an error when i run `npm test`. I also tried to mock the `setInterval` function inside my test block and expected `update()` function to retun a time format value after one millisecond by passing the arguments but it also thrown an error when I run `npm test`.

```
const { update, start, stop } = require("./index.js");

test("millisec innertext format", () => {
    let ms = 0;
    const maxMilliSec = 999;
    const myMin = 10;
    const myMax = 100;
    const secLeadingZero = 0;
    const msLeadingZero = 0;
    setInterval(() => {
      update(myMin, myMax);
    }, 1).then(
      expect(update(ms, myMin, myMax)).toEqual(
        `${msLeadingZero}${msLeadingZero}${ms}`
      )
    );
  });
```

I expected the seconds/milliseconds HTML elements innerTexts to throw an error if the time format conditional rendering in the `update()` function was not met but it was failling to run the test with an error

```
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s
 FAIL  ./index.test.js (11.527 s)
  test clock functionality
    √ returns a truthy value (4 ms)
    √ returns a falsy value (1 ms)
    × millisec innertext format (1 ms)

  ● test clock functionality › millisec innertext format

    TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerText')

      25 |   const msLeadingZero = 0;
      26 |   if (ms < myMin) {
    > 27 |     msEl.innerText = `${msLeadingZero}${msLeadingZero}${ms}`;
         |                   ^
      28 |   } else if (ms > myMin && ms < myMax) {
      29 |     msEl.innerText = `${msLeadingZero}${ms}`;
      30 |   } else if (ms > myMax) {

      at update (index.js:27:19)
```

Please kindly guide me step by step on how I can work on this challenge.